# Isn't A = B same as B = A?

Tags: java, initialization

Why my code is wrong at `initialAge = age;`?

When I saw a solution online it should be swapped as `age = initialAge`. Isn't `A = B` the same as `B = A`?

---

```
public class Person {
    private int age;    

    public Person(int initialAge) {
       if (initialAge >=0){
         initialAge = age;
       }else if( initialAge < 0){
            age =0;
           System.out.println("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.");

       }
        // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
    }

    public void amIOld() {
        // Write code determining if this person's age is old and print the correct statement:
        if (age <  13){
        System.out.println("You are young.");
        } else if ( age >= 13 && age < 18){
          System.out.println("You are a teenager.");  
        }else {
          System.out.println("You are old.");  
        }
    }

    public void yearPasses() {
        age++;
        // Increment this person's age.
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            int age = sc.nextInt();
            Person p = new Person(age);
            p.amIOld();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                p.yearPasses();
            }
            p.amIOld();
            System.out.println();
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `isn't A = B same as B = A` it obviously isn't. `int x = 1; int y = 2; x = y;` What result would you expect if `x = y` and `y = x` were the same? Both being 1 or both being 2?

Comment: In mathematics `=` denotes both assignment and comparison. In programming those operations are separated. When it goes about comparison, `A = B` is the same as `B = A`. When it goes about assignment, it is not. Please note, that I am not speaking about particular notations here, as they vary from language to language. In C++ for example `=` denotes an assignment and `==` a comparison. In Pascal `:=` is assignment and `=` is comparison and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, variable assignment is [right-to-left associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Right-associativity_of_assignment_operators).  For your theoretical example, in an assignment context, `A = B` implies that the value of `B` is now stored in `A`.  Swapping that around means that the value of `A` is stored in `B`.

Mathematical equivalence is performed with the `==` operator. `=` *always* means assignment.

As to why your code is wrong with `initialAge = age` - `initialAge` is a parameter and its value is lost after the method returns, so reassigning it is a moot point.  Your field `age` has the default value of 0 since it's not getting the value for `initialAge`.

Comment: Now I see, I was a little confuse about the different between assignment and comparison  operators.